# Generating random biconnected graph

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Is there a straightforward algorithm for generating a random undirected biconnected graph (given a number of vertices as input)? I understand how to determine if a given graph is biconnected, but I'm struggling to generate one programatically.

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we answer questions but we don't write your code for you.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Apologies if the wording in my question was misinterpreted, but I didn't actually ask for anybody to write code for me. I asked for suggestions of an algorithm that I can use to solve this problem. My question is, "is there a straightforward algorithm for generating a random undirected biconnected graph?" I'm happy to reword the question if you think that it is necessary.

Comment: Should it be an efficient algorithm or can it be any strange thing as long as it works?

Comment: And do you care about the distribution?

Comment: @dingalapadum preferably efficient, since I'll be generating very large graphs. I don't care about the distribution. What I'm currently doing is using a sort of brute force approach with the algorithm to _discover_ biconnected components. Essentially, I'm randomly adding nodes and edges until the graph is considered biconnected, then stopping. This is repeated for the desired number of biconnected components. Whilst it works, it is very slow. Any suggestions to improve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a very simple probabilistic approach:

```
1. Create an empty graph with n nodes
2. For each pair of nodes:
 -Flip a fifty-fifty-coin to decide whether to put an edge in there or not
```

You have O(n^2) pairs of vertices (i.e possible edges) and this will also be the expected running time of this algorithm, since the [random graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_graph) generated by this procedure will be bi-connected [with high probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_high_probability).

Hence, in the end to make sure your graph *really* is bi-connected you just run the regular procedure which you already know.

For the (very unlikely) scenario where the check returns "graph is not bi-connected", just repeat the procedure.

The really intriguing question is "why will I get a biconnected graph w.h.p.?". I will omit the formal proof which is a bit tedious and by how you are asking, I assume you just want something that works and you don't care too much about *why* it works. If I'm wrong and you actually need a proof I suggest you either ask on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) or you drop me a comment - maybe I'll try to make it formal if I find the time.

For the moment, just to give you an intuition for why this will work, consider the following approach of how a proof could go:

- Note that the number of graphs which is *not* bi-connected is equal to the number of graphs with at least one articulation-vertex.
- Let us roughly compute the probability of a single vertex of being an articulation point: The idea is that if `v` is an articulation vertex then it splits the `n`  vertices into two disjoint sets of size `k` and `n-k` such that there is no edge between those sets. Now intuitively it should be more or less clear that `k*(n-k)` coin flips which *all* have to result in "no-edge" is not very probable (basically `(1/2)^(k*(n-k))`). We still have to multiply by `n` (since for each node) but this will still not make a significant difference, and as you might see now it is *very* unlikely for graph with large enough 'n' to not being bi-connected.

(What's still missing is to consider "for each possible partitioning", i.e. for the different choices of `k`, and then maybe be more careful since it would actually be `((n-1)-k)` and `k`, rather than `(n-k)` and `k` because the vertex under consideration is not part of any of the 2 sets... I'm just saying these things to illustrate the kind of details one would still have to worry about for a formal proof...)

Comment: In the trivial case of 3 vertices you would need all 3 adjacent edges to make the graph bi-connected and this will only happen with a probability of 1-in-8. With a 4 vertex graph there is a 1-in-2 chance that a given vertex has zero or one incident edge so is highly likely not to be biconnected. I understand that the probability of non-biconnectivity will drop rapidly as the number of vertices increases but do you have a guide as to what a reasonable minimum number of vertices is where this will work with high probability?

Comment: @MT0 : w.h.p. is not a fixed number. I linked to the wikipedia article it is an expression with very well defined meaning - have a look at it. It means that you can get arbitrarily close to 1 with enough vertices. Also, as it goes with probabilistic algorithms you simply repeat the procedure.... As you noted: for 3 vertices we expect to repeat the procedure 8 times. For 4 we expect 2 times. If you have more vertices than that you will usually get it already after the first try... The more vertices you take the more probable it gets: that's what w.h.p. means.

Comment: This algorithm is not O(n²) - one iteration of the algorithm is O(n²) and if it happens to not produce a biconnected graph then you will have to run it again (and again and again) - the worst-case (which is what Big-O notation denotes) running time for this algorithm is O(Infinity) [but this is unlikely to occur]. You can however state that the **expected** run time is proportional to n².

Comment: @MT0 Expected runtime is what I actually meant... I mean we are talking about randomized algorithms, right? :) Anyway, thanks for noticing. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to is to create a random maximal planar (tri-connected) graph:

- Start with 3 vertices connected in a cycle which forms 2 triangular faces (interior and exterior of the cycle).
- To add each subsequent vertex pick a random face and trisect it with a vertex and 3 edges.

You could stop here - since the graph is tri-connected it is also bi-connected.

However, if you want to remove edges and ensure that you still have a biconnected graph then only remove edges where both incident vertices are degree 3-or-more and test each edge prior to removal using [Hopcroft & Tarjan's Depth-First Search Algorithm to find Biconnected Components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component#Linear_time_depth_first_search) to check for biconnectivity without that edge.

Note - this will always create a planar graph.

Comment: This does not sound like a very *random* biconnected graph, but rather like quite a *specific* kind of biconnected graph... There are bi-connected graphs which are *not* planar (in fact I think most of them probably aren't). With your algorithm you can *never* get a non-planar biconnected. Hence you are sampling from a true *subset* of biconnected graphs. Which means that the graph you get is not a random biconnected graph but rather biconnected one which is conditioned on being planar to...

Comment: As I stated in the last line of my answer - this will always create a planar graph. If the OP (or anyone else looking at this question) is happy with this restriction then it can generate all possible biconnected planar graphs (in a truly random manner). Given that for a maximal planar graph |e| = 3|n|-6 then a maximal planar graph can be generated in O(n) and random edges removed to reduce it to be biconnected in O(n²) for time and memory (since each edge only needs to be tested to see if it can be removed or not at most once and H&Ts DFS algorithm is O(n)).

Comment: How is your algorithm ever going to produce a complete graph? It is bi-connected - hence if an algorithm produces "random bi-connected graphs" it should be able to also produce the complete graph with non-zero probability... I could give you tons of other bi-connected graphs which your algorithm will never produce.... You are only sampling from a *true* subset of the required class.... For that I could go and say "just take the complete graph and remove a random edge"... this will also bi bi-connected for n>3....

Comment: As I stated in the last line of my answer - this will always create a planar graph. So this will create a random biconnected graph within the sub-set of planar graphs. I have never claimed this will create a non-planar graph but it will always create a biconnected graph.

Comment: Yes, I perfectly understand. I also see, that you never claimed it will produce a non-planar graph. What I'm saying is that it *should* be possible to get a non-planar one and the algorithm you proposed fails to do so. Hence, your algorithm is not sampling from the set of *biconnected graphs* but only from a subset, which happens to lie inside this set. An analogy "Q: I want to get the number of the side of a die at random" and  then you answer "A: well, flip a coin, head is 1 tails is 2, 1 and 2 are on a die, hence you get a random number from the die (restricted to a subset)".

Comment: If you really want you can take the biconnected planar graph and add random edges to it - you can then get a non-planar graph that will be guaranteed to be biconnected. The planar biconnected graph can be generated in O(n²) and additional edges can be added in O(e) [and since |e| < |n|² the total time will be O(n²)] - if you add enough edges you will get a complete graph.

Comment: I agree. Changing your algorithm and fixing it might get the job done. From the procedure I propose you get a bi-connected graph uniformly at random among all bi-connected graphs.. Can you tell me something about the distribution you get? I guess it depends on how you decide the nr. of edges you are going to add and where to add them - by the way, how do you plan to those 2 things exactly? Oh, and H&T is linear in the number of edges, not in the number of vertices.... Also, you will need quite a bunch of structures (for instance how do you keep track of the faces)...

Comment: H&T is linear in the number of edges but |e| = 3|n|-6 for a maximal planar graph so it is also going to be linear in the number of vertices as well.

Comment: The algorithm doesn't need fixing - it works. Keeping track of the faces is easy - a face is just a triplet of vertices in cyclic order around the face and these can be trivially stored in an array; each time a face is randomly selected to be trisected you can replace that face with one of its new sub-faces and add the other two new sub-faces at the end of the array - you know how many faces there will be by Euler's formula so you can pre-allocate all the memory.

Comment: Well, the algo as you proposed works - if you want to solve a different problem than what was asked. It needs fixing if you want *all* biconnected graphs to be possible results. As you said in your comments you will need a phase where you *add* edges. That's what I meant with fixing: "adding new steps not mentioned originally in order to adhere to the specification.". This is what the question is asking for, right? I never saw something about planarity in the question. Or that it is ok to only produce a sub-set. I mean otherwise "create cycle; add some random edges" done in O(n). Cheers!